# Need to convert a for loop in node js, since it is causing time complexity

Tags: javascript, json, time-complexity

I have a JSON containg n number of data, I am iterating the data over for loop and bind them in a image. the complexity o(n). I want to reduce the complexity to o(log n)

what is the best alternate to for loop after converting from o(n) to o(log n)

Comment: could you please provide the code you have so far so that we can see exactly what you're doing ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Emilien it is just a nested json having n number of values in it. instead of iteration using for loop, I need to use other ways. since the for loop iterating o(n). I need to reduce to o(log n)